# Join two database table from two different databases in the same server

Tags: codeigniter, drupal

Can we join two table from two different database and both databases are hosted on same servers.

I have a database from drupal 7 and another one from codeigniter 3.0. I can connect drupal database from codeigniter and fetch the record but i want to join drupal database table with codeigniter database.
If possible than please help me.

Comment: Plz see this, if it help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75358/join-tables-in-two-databases-make-query-slow-is-better-to-partition-db

Comment: Thanks a lot but this not helping me. I describe my question that i have two environment first is drupal and second is codeigniter which is hosted on same server and databse which is my sql hosted on same server and i want to call drupal database in codeigniter environment. so i have created a persistent connection in codeigniter and call the drupal database and fetch the record but at a time one database is in active state. So how can i active both database and join table from both database table.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a DB procedure in any of DB, say you write procedure in DB that is connected in Drupal environment, in the procedure you can use both DB tables and then call it from Drupal environment.
Hope this will solve your problem. 
Using same link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75358/join-tables-in-two-databases-make-query-slow-is-better-to-partition-db